# Windows 10 media file duration not shown in explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro N and Explorer isn´t showing me any information about my video/audio files (`.mp3`, `.mp4`, `.wav`, `.mkv`, etc. and none of them have any information).

- All the files have the information since they are shown on another Windows Systems; I activated both columns [duration and length] in Explorer, but they are empty, and I tried `sfc /scannow`

What else could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I installed "Media Feature Pack" under Settings > Apps > Apps and Features > Optional Features > Add a Feature, and restarted, explorer, is showing the correct length of all my files.

Comment: in search there is no media feature pack for me. When I type "media" only Windows Media Player shows up.